# Check convergence of following two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have following two series.

1.$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$  2.$\sum_{2}^{\infty}\ln(\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)$

First I thought both of them are convergent as they are similar to $\sum \ln(n/n)$ and this series is just $0$+$0$..+$0$ and so by limit comparison test both of them converge.

But then when I treat above two as telescoping series I think they must be divergent.

Please clarify me.

Comment: Both sums are divergent.

Comment: Regarding why your first argument fail: $$\ln\frac{n}{n+1} = - \ln\frac{n+1}{n} = -\ln\!\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} =1$, by comparison the first series behaves like $-\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n}$ -- which diverges.

Comment: Why you apply limit to $\ln(1+x)$/$x$

Comment: Will you please explain a bit more..I really want to know how you arrive at conclusion

Comment: Im not tracking your logic, Clement C. Not sure what your limit has to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bullet$ Consider the $n$-th partial sum of both series.

$\bullet$ $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n[\ln(k)-\ln(k+1)]=-\ln(n+1)\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

$\bullet$ $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)>\sum_{k=2}^{n}\ln \left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)=\ln(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the first sum can be written as
$$\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$
Now, notice that all terms except $1$ and $n\to\infty$ cancel out, so we have
$$\ln\frac1\infty=\ln0=-\infty$$
Therefore the sum is divergent. You can apply similar steps for the second sum too.

Comment: No need to go through products -- with sums, this is exactly what the OP referred to when they wrote "But then when I treat above two as telescoping series [...]."

Comment: @ClementC.. You've explained why his first argument fails. I just explained how these series can be solved using another approach. When it is written as a product, it is clear that it diverges.

Comment: @GuyFsone. Arithmetic with infinity is allowed. Infinity is well-defined and we can use it in arithmetics. I really don't give a damn about votes, I'm not here for votes.

Comment: @GuyFsone.  *"I had enough that day. I finally deleted my post."*  - Thank you for sharing your experience, I appreciate that, but not everyone agrees with the community. I'm not here for votes, I'm here to help others. If someone thinks that something is wrong in my post, that's really not my problem. And I'm not going to delete it if someone don't like it.

Comment: @ThePirateBay..thanks for this method...

Answer (score 0):

1)$\log( \dfrac{n}{n+1}) = \log n - \log (n+1)$

$S_n:= \log(1) - \log(2) +  \log(2) - \log(3)..+\log (n) -\log (n+1) =$

$ \log (1) - \log (n+1).$

2)$ \log (\dfrac{n+1}{n-1}) ={ \displaystyle  \int_{n-1}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{x}dx }$

$\gt 2 \dfrac{1}{n+1}.$

1) Find $\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} S_n.$

2) Any resemblance to the harmonic series?